# Excel row redirection with reference to cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am attaching a excel sheet in which i want in Sheet1 if status column turns green then the entire row (viz. A4 to F4) show copy in sheet 2 in front of Dispatched.

Thanks for help in advance. [Excel file Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_XvJH2HCuP_UGZiakpDbDhUMkE/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: What condition causes cells in the Status column to be green?

Comment: Actual date of dispatch will cause status cell green.

Comment: So why is the status in your sample yellow?

Comment: it will turn yellow when you enter work order no.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, your problem is two fold:

1. You want H4 to turn green based on date of dispatch
2. You want to copy all dispatched rows to Sheet2

For comparing dates, make sure that the date you are entering is in the Date format. Else, you will have to convert it. To convert a date, you can use the DATE formula in combination with the string formulae (LEFT, MID , RIGHT).

Once your date formats are in place, I would recommend 2 things
a) Including the term "Dispatched" in your cell if Dispatched and "Pending" if not- This can be done using IF formula which compares dates or using IF(ISBLANK(Cell address of your Date of dispatch cell),"Pending","Dispatched")
b) Conditional Formatting for turning your cell into Green if value is "Dispatched"
c) In the next column- Col I, put the following formula for the entire dataset. Label this variable as "CaseCount"
**=H4&"_"&COUNTIF($H$4:H4,H4)**
This will give you a running count of how many dispatched cases are present.

In Sheet2, in Col B create an index running from Row 4 to expected number of dispatches, and insert the following formula in C4 after including the variable names in Row 3 (whatever is there in Row 3 of Sheet1)

**=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$A$3:$I$10000,MATCH("Dispatched_"&$B4,Sheet1!$I$3:$I$10000,0),MATCH(C$3,Sheet1!$A$3:$I$3,0)),"")**

If you simply want the count of cases in Sheet2!B4, use **COUNTIF(Sheet1!$H$3:$H$10000,"Dispatched")**